# Not understanding the output of fputcsv() function in PHP

Tags: php, fputcsv

I'm not understanding the output I get from this query. Each column is being duplicated, so instead of getting the 7 columns requested, I'm getting 14, each next to its duplicate, but with no header. Here is my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=netID2807.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream, usually downloads
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Callsign', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Time In', 'Time Out', 'County', 'State'));

// go get the data
require_once "dbConnectDtls.php";  // Access to MySQL

$sql = "SELECT callsign, Fname, Lname, logdate, timeout, county, state 
          FROM NetLog 
         WHERE netID = 2807";

foreach($db_found->query($sql) as $row) {
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}
?>
```

Why are all my columns being duplicated, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try `print_r($row);` to see what data you are getting back.

Comment: I'm getting back one listing for reach row, what I would expect. As an example this;                                                                                             Array
(
    [callsign] => AD0TU
    [0] => AD0TU
    [Fname] =>  Craig
    [1] =>  Craig
    [Lname] => Myers
    [2] => Myers
    [logdate] => 2020-09-03 15:09:43
    [3] => 2020-09-03 15:09:43
    [timeout] => 2020-09-03 15:56:44
    [4] => 2020-09-03 15:56:44
    [county] => Livingston 
    [5] => Livingston 
    [state] => MO
    [6] => MO
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your fetch is defaulting to retrieve both associative and numeric-indexed arrays, so it outputs both to the file. You could try specifying that it is only to retrieve either one or the other. I can't see how your data is actually fetched, that must be in your include file.

If you're on mysqli, `fetch_array()` defaults to `MYSQLI_BOTH` which will do as your comment suggests. Instead, specify `MYSQLI_ASSOC` or `MYSQLI_NUM` when the data is retrieved.

Comment: My include file is pretty much a standard PDO credentials file. I use it throughout my fairly large application.

Comment: Some more playing around to understand what you were saying led me to adding this (and some other things) to the code and now it works. $rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);